# Bash: command not found even though it is in PATH

Tags: bash, terminal, path

I am trying to open the Atom code editor using my Terminal.

In Terminal on Mac, when I run `frederik@192 / % atom`, I get `zsh: command not found: atom` even though when I navigate to my PATH at `/usr/local/bin/`, it lists atom. I also checked `/usr/bin/` where `atom` is not listed so there shouldn't be any conflict.

Equally, when I run `ln -s /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh /usr/local/bin/atom`, I get `ln: /usr/local/bin/atom: File exists`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you know that `/usr/local/bin` is on your path then?

Comment: Btw.: I assume that you are using `zsh` and not `bash`.

Comment: Things to check: does `type atom` list "/usr/local/bin/atom"? If it does, what does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/atom` show? If that's a symbolic link, try `ls -lH /usr/local/bin/atom` to see the file it links to.